# Dynamic generation of a Hyperlink in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following scenario

```
<form action="" method="">
      < a href="XXXXX?name=">
      <textarea rows=3 columns=8 name=val><textarea>
</form>
```

The URL of the link tag should be dynamically generated based on the value of the textarea.

Could you suggest me how to go about this

Comment: <textarea rows="3" columns="8" name="val" onchange="this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a').href='newLocation';"><textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="">
      <a id='link' href="">
      <textarea id="txt" rows="3" columns="8" name="val" onChange="updateLink()"><textarea>
</form>


function updateLink()
{
  value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  document.getElementById('link').href = 'something.com?name='+value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="">
  <a href="http://www.example.com?name=" id=link>link text</a>
  <textarea rows=3 columns=8 name=val id=val></textarea>
  <button type=button onclick="useValue()">Use it</button>
</form>
<script>
function useValue() {
  document.getElementById('link').href +=
   encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('val').value);
}
</script>
```

First, you need to fix the HTML markup, closing elements properly and with some content in the link element. Then you need to decide how the operation is to be triggered; I have used the simple approach of a button (using e.g. `onchange` or `unblur` event handler is another possibility, but less intuitive). For easier reference in scripting, add `id` attributes to the relevant elements.

The script itself just picks up a value and appends (with `+=`) it to the `href` value of the link element, after performing % escaping with `encodeURIComponent`, as needed for robustness (e.g., to deal with the character “&” in input so that it becomes % encoded and will thus be passed as part of the value, instead of being treated as a parameter separator).